# Unable to pass data from one child viewcontoller to another childviewcontoller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am using [this](https://github.com/y-hryk/YSLContainerViewController) to implement `ContainerViewContoller`.  Everything is going fine but I'm unable to pass data from one child `ViewController` to an other child `ViewContoller`.

```
CouponCodeViewController *couponVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CouponCodeViewController"];
    couponVC.coponcode=@"this is data";
    couponVC.title = @"Enter Coupon Code";
    [couponVC viewWillAppear:true];

CategoryViewController *categoryVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CategoryViewController"];
    categoryVC.title = @"Choose A Category";



 YSLContainerViewController *containerVC =
    [[YSLContainerViewController alloc]
     initWithControllers:@[couponVC,categoryVC]
     topBarHeight:statusHeight + navigationHeight
     parentViewController:self];
```

When I call my container `ViewController` it loads all childVC at the same time.  Now I want to pass data on click from CouponCodeViewController to CategoryViewController but I'm not able to do so because `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillappear`, and `viewDidAppear` are not called

CouponCodeViewController I am going using this:

```
- (IBAction)skipAct:(id)sender {

//    CategoryViewController *category=[[CategoryViewController alloc]init];
//    category.userInput=@"this is the data";

    [self.scrollMenuDelegate scrollMenuViewSelectedIndex:1];


}

#pragma mark -- YSLContainerViewControllerDelegate
- (void)containerViewItemIndex:(NSInteger)index currentController:(UIViewController *)controller
{
    [controller viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

In `CategoryViewController` my `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` are not called.

How can I pass data from childVC to another ChildVC.

Comment: I have same issue...Have you got any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

That because when you init all controllers, the parent controller doesn't do 'addChildViewController'. It does that only when showing a new controller (I've looked the code).

And after it move from this controller, it removes it from the controller hierarchy.

I would use either delegate or notification to pass the data. 
Another option (which I don't like) is to give the coupons controller a reference from the categoryViewController.